# Where are Photo Stream pictures stored on my Mac?

Tags: iphone, photo-stream

I am trying to locate the pictures from my photo stream to back up on my computer and I cant find them. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photo Stream pictures are stored in

```
~/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets/sub
```

locally.

Comment: It's worth noting that they are only stored there *after* you have configured iPhoto to pull them down from the cloud, and it has subsequently done so.  They won;t just appear unless you occasionally open iPhoto to perform those syncing actions subsequently.

Comment: @stuffe: that's not correct. There's a background process called `iCloud Photos` that always runs and pulls down your Photo Stream photos even when iPhoto isn't open (I just tested it to confirm). See here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120707/does-iphoto-need-to-be-open-in-order-to-download-photo-stream-photos

Comment: Interesting, and thanks! Mine doesn't appear to be working then...

Comment: Also, if you are on a new Mac with Photos, the Photo Stream photos are now in ~/Library/Containers and only the subscribed photos and using iCloud sharing are in iLifeAssetManagement under A S in Library. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182157/ for details