# After migrating to iCloud Photo Library can the iLifeAssetManagement folder be deleted?

Tags: icloud, photos, photo-stream, photos.app

Before iCloud Photo Library and Photos.app in OS X 10.10.3, we had iCloud PhotoStream. iCloud PhotoStream synced its photos to the `~/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement` folder (and subfolders). Even though PhotoStream only synced 1000 photos, that folder could get rather large, but you had to live with it.

Now that iCloud Photo Library exists, and everything is stored in the cloud (and the cloud copy is "the truth"), I'm assuming that the `iLifeAssetManagement` folder is no longer used and can be deleted. Does any one know for sure if that's true?

In my case, the folder hasn't had changes since I upgraded to iCloud Photo Library, which would indicate it's not being used.

Comment: Photo Stream is still used so long as "My Photo Stream" is enabled in Photos preferences (Preferences > iCloud > My Photo Stream), even if iCloud Photo Library is also enabled. This provides backwards compatibility with devices that either can't or don't have iCloud Photo Library enabled, but do have Photo Stream enabled.

Comment: @tubedogg yes, and I have that enabled. However, I still don't see anything changing in my `iLifeAssetManagement` folder. It's worth adding that there aren't any devices using my iCloud account which don't have iCloud Photo Library enabled, so My Photo Stream seems redundant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer appears to be "Yes, it can". After a month of the folder not being touched I finally deleted it and it hasn't caused any issue whatsoever. However, if any device using your iCloud account is still using Photo Stream (for whatever reason), you may still need the folder.